# TortoiseSVN importing .svn folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I got some old .svn folders (from 2012) and I want to important them into a new repository. The old repository were on a server that is down. How can I get them into a local repository?

I already tried creating a new repository, checking it out, copying the .svn into it and to relocate it with TortoiseSVN. But I get the error that the uuid is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .svn folder has "pristine" copies of the checked out files, so one thing you could do is `svn revert` everything to get the pristines out of it:

```
# do this in the same folder that contains the .svn folder
svn revert -R .
```

You can do the same thing TortoiseSVN by right-clicking on the folder that contains the .svn folder, selecting "Revert", checking all items you want, and then hit "OK".

Once you have the pristines, just add/import them into your new repository.  You won't get any history since that's stored on the server, but it's unclear if that's a deal-breaker for you.